# How to say best grandma

Tags: translation

I am looking for a name to be called by my new granddaughter.

Comment: Cosa c'è di male in *nonna*?

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE! Have you tried a dictionary to look for the translation? In this site we expect questions that show an effort to research before asking. See [our on-topic page](http://italian.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

"Nonna" is definitely the most used way.

If they are being mocking/playful, they may go for the diminutive "Nonnina", but in all honesty they will likely pick what to call you, not you.

In Italian, since the proper noun for grandmother is already fairly short, we don't really have a specialized shorter version like grandma / granny

Answer (score 2):

As it has already been stated, the most common word for "grandma" is *nonna*.

Some [terms of endearment](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/nonna/), similar to the English words "Granny"/"Nana"/"Nanny", are used:

> Dim. e vezz. **nonnétta** e **nonnettina**, **nonnina**; vezz. **nonnùccia**.